# print the multiple outputs stored in a variable on HTML page in rails in formatted way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, output-formatting

I am new to rails, I have used rails count to get a count of my working and non working assets and stored them in variables. The count is grouped by asset type. When I try to print the count on my index page, its printing the count but in raw format. I need to print it in proper format. Here is the code from my controller-

```
@instock_working_type=EquipmentAsset.count(:conditions=>"oos=0 and location='In Stock'", :group=>"asset_type")
@instock_non_working_type=EquipmentAsset.count(:conditions=>"oos=1 and location='In Stock'", :group=>"asset_type")
```

now I have to print @instock_working_type and @instock_non_working_type on my index page for which I have used

```
<td><b>working Devices Type wise</td>
            <td><%=h @instock_working_type %></td>


    <td><b>Non working Devices Type wise</td>
            <td><%=h @instock_non_working_type %></td>
```

But the out put which I am getting on the browser is something like -

```
 {"MVT600"=>1} {"MVT380"=>1, "MVT600"=>2}
```

which I want in proper format like-
**MVT380**=1
**MVT600**=2

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a hash in instance variable, loop through it and display the values accordingly after accessing.

```
@hash_var.each do |key,val|
   "#{key}=#{val}"
end
```

your current @instock_working_type is hash which is displayed on browser, it's a hash which has been grouped using the criteria as key. replace @hash_var with @instock_working_type and try

Comment: I am sorry, but can you elaborate that using the chunk which I've given above?